# AngularJS: Best practice for storing a shopping cart item

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a small Angular.js application that basically consists of a catalog and a shopping cart. Still new to the library, I'm looking for the best practice for storing the user's shopping cart contents.

So far, I found that $rootScope allows maintaining data in "session-like" behavior.

However, I doubt it's the best practice. What approach would you suggest exploring to implement this?

Thanks,

Comment: Question is too broad. Too much unknowns to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest exploring `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. But that may not be suitable for keeping items in longterm as this is browser-specific. It may be a starting point, though.

Comment: Thanks. I found custom services and will try that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is some exercise or homework, right? (Please don't tell me that the world needs yet another shopping cart implementation.) ;-)

There's only one sensible place to store a shopping cart and that is on the server side.
For example that way you can add to the cart from your mobile and do the actual checkout from your notebook.

You do not really want to have different shopping carts on each device you use, right?

Also you might want to show related items, which also involves the server.

Comment: Hi, it's for learning purpose. Am looking at the custom service implementation now.

Comment: Of course the cart need to live on the server but also in angular.  You might want to share data between several angular components that is based on cart data!